# subscribing to any topic by mosquitto broker

Tags: mosquitto

I am using mosquitto broker to subscribe for messages from machines to my machine. I want to receive all the messages irrespective of the topic. For that I use the following command

```
mosquitto_sub -t \#
```

ofcourse it receives messages for all topics. But when I type the command and press enter the first thing I see is 0. What is that 0 and why is that 0? For your information my machine has ubuntu 14.04 as OS. I want only the messages which are published and no default values like 0. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a retained message.
To get the associated topic, you can run mosquitto_sub with the -v arg:

```
mosquitto_sub -t \# -v
```

To clear a retained message, you must send a null retained message (-n and -r args)

```
mosquitto_pub -r -n -t *topic*
```

If you want only fresh messages, you can use the -R arg:

> ```
>    -R
>         If this argument is given, messages that are received that have the retain
>         bit set will not be printed. Messages with retain set are "stale",
>         in that it is not known when they were originally published. When
>         subscribing to a wildcard topic there may be a large number of 
>         retained messages. This argument suppresses their display.
> ```

```
 mosquitto_sub -t \# -v -R
```